# repeated segements HL7 in pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, hl7

I want to know how can I use HL7 input (or what step can I use) to read all segments of a message HL7 even if the segement is repeated 
example:

```
DG1|1|I10C|G30.0|Alzheimer's disease with early onset|20160406|W|||||||||
DG1|2|I10C|E87.70|Fluid overload, unspecified|20160406|W|||||||||
```

because in my recent transformation i got just the second segment DG1 so the first one is lost as information.
my steps to extract message hl7 :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for inserting data from multiple segments to database in pentaho kettle 6.0,
I used the USER DEFINED JAVA CLASS step, Hapi project classes and methodes (Pipeparser, xmlencode(Message)) to split the message and to convert it to xml output, then i loop (using Xpath on the specific segment, in my case the DG1 segments see attached[image]) for every fields in HL7 message.

Answer (score 0):

The field following the segment identifier is a sequence number. This isn't necessarily intended to uniquely identify the repeating segment, but it effectively does.

The expectation is that the receiving system parses repeating segments into a one-to-many relationship to the parent information. Whether or nota sequence number field is present

Comment: so please how can I get the other segments DG1, is there a solution in kettle ??it's urgent, thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't consider then context of your question. I know HL7, but not pentaho kettle